# Magento Connect Manager Console not showing

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

In My magento connect manager when I try to install/uninstall any extension my console does not show anything it only a blank white space there and only creates magento.flag file but it does not install/uninstall any extension.

I have also checked console iframe code is blank just html, head and body only.

[image]

Comment: Have you already checked the permissions of your /downloader folder?

Comment: yes its 775....

Answer (score 0):

Please remove connect.cfg rom your_magento_folder/downloader